# How do I remove labelled emails from my inbox?

Tags: gmail, gmail-labels

I have emails in my inbox that have been labelled under different label names. I now want to remove these emails from the inbox so that they only appear under their individual labels. So far, I can only remove the emails from the inbox by opening each email and removing the 'inbox' label, which is a time-consuming task. Is there a simpler method to remove multiple labelled emails *already in the inbox* from the inbox?

Answer (score 4):

Select one or more emails by clicking on the box to the left of each message.

Once the first one is selected, the "archive" button will appear at the top. Clicking Archive removes the inbox label from each of the messages/conversations that you selected. No other labels are removed when you click Archive.